# How to make the total appear separately in the Python terminal

Tags: python, list

I made an extremely simple Python program to add all the numbers(10, 20 and 30) in a list called ‘prices’.
Then, I made a variable called ‘total’ and set it to zero.
In the end, I used a ‘for’ loop to add it all and print the answer, but I got the following output:

```
Total:  10
Total:  30
Total:  60
```

My code:

```
prices = [10, 20, 30]

total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price
    print(f"Total: ", total)
```

I want the print the final output only once in the terminal.

I am a beginner so, please give me an answer which is not too complex and at my level.
I made the code myself from an exercise in a YouTube video

Comment: @Saatvik. Your code is working under Python 3.12.0rc3. The correct way to use f-string format `print(f"Total: {total}")`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you just need to put the print statement outside of the for loop.

```
prices = [10, 20, 30]
total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price
print('Total: ',  total)
```

More simply, you can use the built in sum function,

```
print('Total: ', sum(prices))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to coding! So this seems to be an indentation based semantic error. Your problem will be fixed if you align the print statement to the left, i.e.

```
prices = [10, 20, 30]

total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price

print(f"Total: ", total)
```

When the print statement was inside the loop, it was printing the value of the variable `total` at every iteration. But when you take it out of the for-loop, it just prints the final value. Indentation is super important in python-coding since we don't really use curly braces { } like in Java or C++. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Python the indentation matters, since the print statement is inside the for loop, you are getting total print at multiple line.

```
prices = [10, 20, 30]
total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price
print('Total: ',  total)
```

but much efficient way to improve the code is to make use of built in function `sum()`

```
prices = [10,20,30]
print('Total: ', sum(prices))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the print() function inside the ‘for’ loop. So, the total value gets printed in every iteration of the loop. To print the total only once, you need to put print() function outside the ‘for’ loop. Modified code:

```
prices = [10, 20, 30]

total = 0
for price in prices:
    total += price

print(f"Total: ", total) #Put the print() function outside the for loop
```

Output:

```
60
```

BTW, your naming practices are pretty good for a beginner level :)